# Interpolating surface normals from scattered data

Tags: matlab, interpolation, surf

I have scattered data `[x(:),y(:),z(:)]` and I want, given a new point `(x1,y1)`, to interpolate the surface normal at this point.
Currently I'm using "scatteredInterpolant" in matlab, and then interpolate the derivatives of the surface at the wanted point.
I would like to find a more efficient option that I can convert to mex using matlab's coder.

my current code:

```
F = scatteredInterpolant(X(:), Y(:), Z(:)); 
[Xq,Yq] = meshgrid(X(1,:),linspace(Y(1,1),Y(end,1),size(Y,1))); 
Zq = F(Xq,Yq); 
[ZX,ZY] = gradient(Zq); 
gradX=interp2(Xq, Yq, ZX,X1, Y1); 
gradY=interp2(Xq, Yq, ZY,X1, Y1);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: please post the code you already have and a set of input and output data

Comment: F = scatteredInterpolant(X(:), Y(:), Z(:));
 [Xq,Yq] = meshgrid(X(1,:),linspace(Y(1,1),Y(end,1),size(Y,1)));
    Zq = F(Xq,Yq);
    [ZX,ZY] = gradient(Zq);
gradX=interp2(Xq, Yq, ZX,X1, Y1);
gradY=interp2(Xq, Yq, ZY,X1, Y1);

Comment: Hi there - if you press `edit` above you can add this code into your original question.  It's difficult to read code in comments.